# Display of world axis and grid is broken

Tags: axis

In Blender 2.83 the world axis and the floor grid display seems broken. I'm new to the software and I'm not sure what is the cause of this problem.
I don't want to continue working on a corrupted file or software.
I attach an image to give you the idea.
I'm working on MAc OS Sierra, with no OpenGL or CUDA.
Thank you for your help.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check these 2 values in View window... This happens if you change these values to very big values... For example, if you put in second value something like 10000000000, it may give you this graphic glitch that is created because the first number is low and the second is too big...

[image]

Try to lower End value or increase Clip start value and let me know if it helped

Comment: Yes , that was it! thanks I didn't realize that the high clipping value was distarting the axis and the grid.

Comment: No problem, I thought that it may be the reason because I see that you are making some city and people often just put 9999999 or 100000000 to that value, I have seen it few times before